# Windows SSHFS/SFTP mounting clients

Tags: windows, windows-7, remote-access

I'm looking for a solution that lets me 'mount' a remote server via ssh or sftp protocols.

- The remote directory should show up as a drive letter on Windows.
- (optional) More than one simultaneous connection possible.
- Free or paid solutions are acceptable.
- Windows 7 is a must.

Things I've tried so far:

- [sshfs](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) - This mostly works, but for some reason when you use Notepad++ to access files over an sshfs connection, Notepad++ can't properly determine line endings. Also has some bugs in the UI (you have to save the password to get it to work), and the developer appears to be absent.
- [SFTP Net Drive](http://sftpnetdrive.com/) - The free version works, but I get frequent 20 second pauses in open dialogs. Given that the 'server' is a VM running locally, this isn't a network issue, and it DOESN'T happen with sshfs.
- [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/expandrive) - Seems to be working in my initial tests. No odd lags or bad behaviors. I wouldn't mind a slimmer solution (it supports N different cloud providers as well as SFTP), but it DOES work.

I'd obviously like a free solution, but if none exists, I'll happily pay money for something.

Update: I've added answers below with the ones I've actually had some success with.

Comment: See my answer here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/46547/34738

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Out of the ones you listed: I would be cautious with [sshfs](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) as the underlying driver (Dokan) has not been updated for quite a while, and even though it supports Windows 7, it has known issues with Windows 8.x (and probably with Windows 10).

[ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/expandrive) works like a charm, and I don't see the need for a "slimmer solution", you can simply not use the protocols you don't need.

I'm surprised by the behavior you describe regarding [SFTP Net Drive](http://sftpnetdrive.com/); I have it installed at many customers' locations and it's probably the most reliable piece of software I've ever tried (when properly configured). Personally, out of 100+ installations, I've never seen the behavior you describe.

Another excellent option that you may consider is [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/). Like ExpanDrive it supports a plethora of protocols, but don't be intimidated, it's easy to use and fairly lightweight.

Also, you may check out [NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/); very similar to ExpanDrive and WebDrive, with a wide support for many back-ends, and a clean and easy-to-use configuration interface.

Comment: Do WebDrive and NetDrive actually mount the remote (giving it a drive letter)? I kind of had the impression that they were kind of Explorer add-in things, but that they didn't really present a drive to the system.

Comment: Nope, both of them DO actually mount your remote server as a drive (with drive letter) in Windows. Download them and try yourself. :)

Comment: Interesting: I had small troubles with ExpanDrive (it would sometimes exit without warning when disconnecting a drive). While removing it to try WebDrive, I found the Dokan library still in place, and I wonder if it was causing trouble for sftp net drive and expandrive.

Comment: WebDrive triggers bad behavior in Notepad++ - for some reason after every save, Notepad++ thinks the file has been changed and reloads it.

Comment: NetDrive may be easy to configure, but for some reason I can't get it to talk to the system in question, and it's error message is completely useless.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Please feel free to submit a ticket to WebDrive's online help desk and give us some detail about the bad behavior (I work for the developer of the product). Maybe there is something in the configuration settings that we can look at. If you are running a trial version of WebDrive, please put "evaluation" in the registration code/customer info. field. You can access our helpdesk here: http://www.webdrive.com/product-support/webdrive/

Comment: Per previous comments: After working with product support, WebDrive works fine with Notepad++ if you disable all caching and asnyc options.

Comment: Which of these programs allow you to customize the linux permissions when writing to the drives?  SFTP Net Drive defaults to rw-rw-r. Netdrive defaults to rw-r-r (better). I need customization because I would like to preserve the file permissions on the server.

Comment: SFTP Net Drive disconnects repeatedly with `Connection lost due to error 10035`

Answer (score 7):

There are some forks of win-sshfs and the Dokan library, which seem to get it working much better.

https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany

https://github.com/dimov-cz/win-sshfs

https://github.com/tuiSSE/win-sshfs (with a very different GUI and more than 300 commits over the original win-sshfs; however, it is no longer being developed, it asked to be merged into dimov-cz).

I've tried both of these forks, and they seem to work reasonably well regarding transfer speed and latency. None of them is able to restore connection after network connection is lost or after wakeup from sleep. On the other hand, they work flawlessly in Explorer and other file managers. They both run (at least) on Win 7 64bit.

The dimov-cz fork takes about 30 MB of RAM, the tuiSSE takes almost 80 MB RAM.

Comment: You can generate a rsa-key when you install git-scm.  rsa-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 ==> C:/Users/<YOUR_USER>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub then echo id_rsa.pub on the server to /home/<your_accessed_user>/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: @StefanSteiger: ??? I already use key-based login...

Answer (score 4):

I am using [NetDrive 1.3.4](http://www.downloadsource.net/1756222/NetDrive/), which is the last version free for non-commercial home use, and it works fine on Windows 8.

Comment: netdrive is no longer free for home use.  it's a 30 day trial, then you purchase

Comment: NetDrive 2.* is trialware, but 1.* is freeware.

Comment: From what I can tell, 1.3.4.0 does not support any form of encryption just raw FTP and WebDAV.

Answer (score 3):

ExpanDrive works for me, and their licensing (per-user, not per computer) is very reasonable.

This is the one I ended up buying. I do have an issue (I'm going to submit a support ticket today) where it has a tendancy to pause for 10-20 seconds when first opening a directory.

Updated: 
After several months use, I'm less fond of ExpanDrive than when I started out. I did submit a ticket about the lags, but never got a real fix, nor did I pursue it. More importantly, I've run into an odd behavior that I think I have to attribute to caching: Sometimes, when I change a folder on the target system directly, it isn't properly reflected on the Windows system that's using ExpanDrive.

In one case, I renamed a folder using an ssh command line to the target. I then used Notepad++ on the Windows system and found BOTH the old and new names were showing up in the open file dialog! I can't reproduce this on demand, so I haven't submitted a ticket yet, and I'm also a version or two behind the latest.

Comment: And on further issues with Expandrive: for unknown reasons it's window stopped showing up, making it impossible to use. I updated and now there seems to be some sort of caching issue causing bad behavior in Notepad++.

Answer (score 3):

I did try WebDrive, and (after some back and forth with the developers) got it working perfectly. The secret is to disable all caching AND the asnyc option. You have to do BOTH in order to get it to work reliably with Notepad++.

The only downside relative to ExpanDrive is that the license is per machine, not per user, so if you have more than one computer, WebDrive would be more expensive.

Comment: One more thing: it may also be necessary to turn of the 'Enable Delayed Close' feature for perfect handling with Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

There is a free SSHFS implementation for Windows [here](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win/releases). It doesn't appear to be related to Dokan. It is generally paired with [WinFsp](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp/releases), which can be thought of as FUSE for Windows. Both of these are actively maintained as of this writing.

Comment: works like magic! Very integrated with Windows. Map a volume with UNC syntax \\sshfs\REMUSER@HOST[\PATH] and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still ISO a Windows SSHFS client, I'm using [MountainDuck](https://mountainduck.io/), which is authored by the same folks as CyberDuck FTP client. I like the SSH key feature. The biggest advantage I can see is that you don't have to open additional ports on a router or create extra firewall rules. It mounts the remote FS as a drive letter, but I'd rather have the option of mounting as a UNC path because I have a lot of network volumes in use.

The Windows client is compatible with 7 and up. There's a Mac version as well. The (cheap, paid) license allows installation on multiple machines.

It supports FTP, FTP-SSL, SFTP, WebDAV, Amazon S3, Backblaze cloud storage, Google Cloud Storage, Rackspace Cloud Files, Swift, Windows Azure Storage, Dropbox, Google Drive, MS One Drive.