# Securely mount a drive on another computer over the Internet

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management

I want a free way to access a directory on one computer from another computer (not on same network) as a drive letter in Windows Explorer. (Both machines run Windows 10 and I have full access to both computers.)

The only thing that could actually accomplish this for me was using [bitvise](https://www.bitvise.com/) as the "server" and [SFTPNetDrive](http://www.sftpnetdrive.com/) as the "client". This worked, but was unusably slow.

There must be some simple way to accomplish this task. Possibly some native-to-Windows solution?

Comment: do you have or know if there is an admin user on the connected pc?
if so, do you know the login credentials?

Comment: What OS does the remote computer run? Linux, Windows, ...? What prices are acceptable for you? If bitvise was too slow, how fast was it and how fast do you need it to be? Note that this heavily depends on your Internet speed and the server's Internet speed. There's nothing the software could do about slow Internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount SFTP on Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38457/mount-sftp-on-windows)

Comment: Both machines run Windows and I have full access to both.

Comment: VPN+standard windows file sharing.

Comment: gabor, please tell us the exact speed you achieve with bitvise (for instance transfer a 3GB file and tell us how many minutes/seconds it took). And also run an Internet speed test on both machines, and tell us the upload and download speeds for both. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Alejandro: Not duplicate, the asker is open to other solutions than SFTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a VPN (virtual private network). With a VPN, you  can access any services as if they were present in your local network. This is how companies connect home office users to the company network.

There is a VPN functionality built-in with Windows 10 Pro, but I was unable to figure out in which [Windows 10 editions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions) it is available.

[OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) is a free solution.

Here's how it fits your needs:

- it's [available for Windows](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html)
- you would mount network shares like you always do (`net use` or in Windows Explorer), thus giving you a drive letter.
- it's [secure through cryptography](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/security-overview.html)