# How do I mount an sftp share in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, sftp

Looking for foss/libre (free as in freedom) software to mount sftp either as a drive or a directory on windows 10, with recursive search availalbe. Solution from [Mount SFTP on Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38457/mount-sftp-on-windows) is WinSCP, it can do file transfer but it does not do the mount or the search. From [Windows SSHFS/SFTP mounting clients](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13875/windows-sshfs-sftp-mounting-clients) sshfs appears to be a bit buggy in Windows with last release in 2011. Other suggested options are not foss/libre (free as in freedom) as far as I understood.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but how about https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win ? Seems better maintained / more recently updated than win-sshfs.